# How can i emulate the Shift + F5 keystroke?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently using the following code SendKeys.SendWait("{+F5}"); in a wpf application using forms as described in msdn but it throws an exception. I also tried other combinations like ("{+(F5)}") etc but no luck. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SendKeys.SendWait("+{F5}");
```

Make sure your receiving application has focus, first.